# How to get the ASCII character in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I get this **ƒ** character from the ASCII table..? I have tried like this.

```
  txt2 = (char)131;
```

I can able to get till 127 values only.. If I give more than 127 its returning NULL value. So how can I get till 255 ?

Comment: `ƒ` isn't ASCII... it is Unicode. `char ch = 'ƒ'`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ƒ` isn't ASCII... it is Unicode, [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK' (U+0192)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char//index.htm).

```
char ch = 'ƒ';
```

or

```
char ch = (char)0x0192;
```

or

```
char ch = '\x0192';
```

There are only 128 characters in the ASCII set (0-127), and there are no non-american letters (there are only *A-Z* and *a-z*)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary That three lines of code have been tested on my Visual Studio 2012. You can write `char ch = (char)402` and it will be equivalent.

Comment: i deleted the comment because the char cant be null. (i just thought about it for a sec) maybe OP is saying `NULL` is shown in text view.